# Prove by induction (combinatorics)

Tags: combinatorics

Let $Ω_n = \{1, 2, . . . , n\}$ and for 0 ≤ k ≤ n let $Ω^{k}$ be be the collection of k-element subsets of $Ω_n.$

Define the number $S^{n}_k$ as cardinality of $Ω^{k}_n$

Prove that $S^{n}_k$=$n\choose k$ by the SPMI (strong induction) on $(n+k)$. Show the equality for the first pairs of $(n,k)$, formulate and inductive hypothesis, and prove the inductive step using the identities $S^{n}_k+S^{n}_{k+1}=S^{n+1}_{k+1}$ and $n \choose k$ +  $n \choose {k+1}$= ${n+1} \choose {k+1}$.

I don't know if this problem is too easy or I am missing the point

Approach

Proof by strong induction

Base case:
 $S^{n}_0=\emptyset =1$
${n \choose 0 }=1$
$S^{n}_1=1$
${n \choose 1 }=1$

Inductive step Assume  $S^{l}_i = {l \choose i}$ for all $1<l\leq n$ and $1<i\leq k$. Need to show  $S^{n+1}_{k+1} = {n+1 \choose k+1}$

Is that the right way to go? what does "SPMI" on (n+k) mean?

Comment: What does “SPMI” mean in the first place. And what is $S^n_k$?

Comment: I already made the corrections